# Convert curl send file to python request

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests

For anonfiles, they only give the curl function to upload a file,

`curl -F "file=@test.txt" https://api.anonfiles.com/upload`

and I want to use python requests for this.

I tried

```py
import requests
data = requests.put(url = "https://api.anonfiles.com/upload",data=open('file.txt','r').read() )
print(data.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import requests

with open('test.txt', 'rb') as fp:
    r = requests.post('https://api.anonfiles.com/upload', files={'file': fp})
print(r.json())
```

Output:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "file": {
            "url": {
                "full": "https://anonfiles.com/oa28JcS2ya/test_txt",
                "short": "https://anonfiles.com/oa28JcS2ya"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "id": "oa28JcS2ya",
                "name": "test.txt",
                "size": {
                    "bytes": 580,
                    "readable": "580 B"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More information here: [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)